# Change image and text info with one button click prev and next simultaneously

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, text, buttonclick

I'm a absolute beginner to HTML CSS and javascript. I have almost finished the website I'm building but stuck at one javascript thing... On different pages I have made image arrays with Javascript, no problems there. Only the text info next to the image has to change with the same button click.... I have tried several things but I need some help. I hope someone will help me.

HTML

```
<div><img style="width:573px" src="images/omejan.jpg" class="omejan-images"></div>

<div><p class="titel">ome<br>Jan</p>
<p class="platte-tekst">Een dressoir, bloemenvaas, lamp, kalender, telefoon en een lijstje. Elke week verse bloemen voor hun broer.</p>
<p class="voetnoot">Onderdeel van het project de tantes</p>
<p id="imageinfo" class="foto-info">2007</p><!--only this text line has to change-->
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <div><button class="pijl-links" onclick="prev()"><img src="images/pijl_links.svg"></button></div>
    <div><button class="pijl-rechts" onclick="next()"><img src="images/pijl_rechts.svg"></button></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Javascript

```
var slider_img = document.querySelector('.omejan-images');
var images = ['omejan_2007.jpg', 'omejan_2009.jpg', 'omejan_2010.jpg', 'omejan_2011.jpg', 'omejan_2013.jpg', 'omejan_2014.jpg'];
var i = 0;

//var imageinfo = ['2007', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2013', '2014'];
//document.getElementById("imageinfo").innerHTML= imageinfo[0];
//I have tried the two lines above, won't work. 

function prev(){
    if(i <= 0) i = images.length;   
    i--;
    return setImg();             
}

function next(){
    if(i >= images.length-1) i = -1;
    i++;
    return setImg();             
}

function setImg(){
    return slider_img.setAttribute('src', "images/"+images[i]);
    
}

////next option I have tried

function shuffle(){
    var images1 = [], descriptions = [],
    index1 = 0;
    images1[0] = "images/omejan_2007.jpg";
    images1[1] = "images/omejan_2009.jpg";
    images1[2] = "images/omejan_2010.jpg";
    images1[3] = "images/omejan_2011.jpg";
    images1[4] = "images/omejan_2013.jpg";
    images1[5] = "images/omejan_2014.jpg";
    descriptions[0] = "2007";
    descriptions[1] = "2009";
    descriptions[2] = "2010";
    descriptions[3] = "2011";
    descriptions[4] = "2013";
    descriptions[5] = "2014";
    index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images1.length);
    document.getElementById("omejan-images").src = images1[index1];
    document.getElementsByClassName("foto-info")[0].innerText = descriptions[index1];
  }

///With the code above I was glad to have some movement on the page, only it is shuffle... I want the Images and text in order. Couldn't solve it
  // myself...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `objects` here in order to keep your image information together - e.g.

```
const images = [{
    src: 'omejan_2007.jpg',
    description: '2007'
}, {
    src: 'images/omejan_2009.jpg',
    description: '2009'
},
{
//...etc
}];
```

As we're still using an array (just an *array of objects* instead of strings), your `next()` and `prev()` functions still work to set the index. So, we'd just need to make a slight change to `setImg`:

```
function setImg(){
    const image = images[i];
    const description = document.getElementById("imageinfo"); //this could also be declared at the top with your other variables
    description.innerHTML = image.description;
    slider_img.src = image.src;
}
```

---

As an aside, there are a few other "code review"-y things I've noticed.

Typically, you should try to avoid `onclick="function"` attributes. The more preferred way of doing this is to use event handlers, e.g.

```
<!-- adding ids to the buttons -->
<div><button class="pijl-links" id="prev"><img src="images/pijl_links.svg"></button></div>
<div><button class="pijl-rechts" id="next"><img src="images/pijl_rechts.svg"></button></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener("click", prev);
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", next);
</script>
```

`i` isn't the *most descriptive* variable name - this should probably be renamed to something like `current_image`

`var` is no longer recommended for variable declarations - instead you should look to use `const` (for constant variables) or `let`.

You are returning from `setImg`, `next` and `prev`, but not doing anything with the return value. You probably don't need to do this? If it's to do with the page refreshing and/or jumping, you can add the `type` attribute to the button to stop it from being treated as a submit

```
<button type="button" class="pijl-links" id="prev"><img src="images/pijl_links.svg"></button>
```

Comment: thank you so so much!!! It's working. I'm also changing your other code-reviews. Thanks!

Comment: @marlies you're more than welcome, glad I could help :)